# How to insert every value of array variable in database

Tags: php

How to insert every value of array variable in database, whenever i try to insert value using array variable it gives me a error "Array to string conversion".Actually i want to store the attendance of students into "attendance database table", i am retrieving id and name of students from students database, this information of students is being stored in array but when i use array variable"`$result`" to insert the name of student into attendence_tbl database it gives me error of array to string conversion.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="templatemo-line-header" style="margin-top: 0px;" >
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray"/><span  class="span_blog txt_darkgrey txt_orange">Attendance Form</span>
                        <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
 <?php  
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
 include("config.php");?>
<div class="form-container">
<form method="post" action="" role="form">
 <!-- <div class="container"> -->
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <?php
  $qs=mysql_query("select * from student_table");
  ?>
  <table border=1>  
  <?php 
  $c=0;
  while($stid=mysql_fetch_row($qs))
  {         

  ?>

 <tr>
 <td ><?php echo $stid[0]?></td>
 <td><?php echo $stid[1]?></td>
 <td>

 <select name="present[]" >
 <option value=""> ---Select Attendence--- </option>
 <option value="P"> Present </option>
 <option value="A"> Absent </option>

 </select></td>

 </tr>


 <?php
     $stud= $stid[0];
  $subj= $stid[1];

 $location_vars = array(/*"stud" ,*/ "subj");

 $result[] = compact("nothing_here", $location_vars);

 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 $c++;
   }
 // echo "</select>"."<br>";
 echo $c;
 $e=0;
  if(isset($_POST['present'])){  
 foreach($_POST['present'] as $present){
 print_r($result);

 $query=mysql_query("Insert into tbl_attendence (StudentRollNumber,SubjectId,Attendence,Date)VALUES('$stud','$stid','$present','$date')");
  $e++;

  }}
  ?>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div> <!--col-lg-4-->

  <button type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>

</form>
</div> <!--form-container-->
</div><!--container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is `$result` related to `$_POST['present']`?

Comment: What's the value of `$result`? Which element of the array should go into the database?

Comment: Use MySQLi functions, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to put an array variable data directly into table which is supposed to throw error,

Here is the solution.

For adding all value of an array directly into table you have to use first convert array into json and then need to insert it into database. like this..

```
$resultJson = json_encode($result);
$query = mysql_query("Insert into tbl_attendence (StudentRollNumber,SubjectId,Attendence,Date)VALUES(".$stud.", ".$resultJson.", ".$present.", ".$date.")");
```

AND if you want to add all array value into database for each value per row separately then you have to make sure run the loop and then insert each value into database for each record.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to upload something like this:

```
Array([1] => '1', [2] => '2')
```

into a table, which would not work. So you'd have to use JSON to *stringify* the array. Example:

```
<?php
    $value = 'Some string';
    $value2 = 'Some other string';
    $values = Array('String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3');

    $json_values = json_encode($values);

    $mysqli = new mysqli('HOSTNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE'); // Connecting to SQL Server

    // Checking if connection was successfull
    if( $mysqli->connect_errno ){
        echo 'There was an error connection to the SQL Server<br>';
        echo '(' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
        exit; // FAIL
    }

    // Preparing a statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT into TABLENAME(value, value2, values) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');

    // Checking if php prepared the statement successfully
    if(!$stmt){
        echo 'There was an error preparing the statement!';
        exit;
    }

    if( !$stmt->bind_param('sss', $value, $value2, $json_values) ){
        echo 'There was an error binding params to the statement!';
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to post arrays into DB I use this approach:

```
       //database connection class
      class Database{ 

    // specify your own database credentials 
    private $host = "YOUR HOST"; 
    private $db_name = "DATABASE NAME"; 
    private $username = "USERNAME"; 
    private $password = "PASSWORD"; 
    public $conn; 

    // get the database connection 
    public function getConnection(){ $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}

//model class
class Model{ 
    // database connection
    private $conn; 

    // constructor with $db as database connection 
    public function __construct($db){ 
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // add info to db
function create($fieldset){
     $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO 
               tbl_attendence 
            SET 
                 $fieldset";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}



//part that will handle the post

// get database connection 
$database = new Database(); 
$db = $database->getConnection();

//instatiate model
$model = new Model($db);



//function that will filter posted values
 function filter($value){

 $value = trim($value);
 $value = strip_tags($value);
 $value = stripslashes($value);
 $value = htmlentities($value);
 return $value; 
}

         if(!empty($_POST)){
              //Get Variables
                foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

                    //this part will tackle values which are arrays
                    if(is_array($value)){
                                $val=implode(",",filter($value));
                                $groupVal[] = $val;
                                $groupKeys[] = $key;
                        }

                        else{
                              $groupVal[] = $this->filter($value);
                              $groupKeys[] = $key;
                        }
                }

            //count items in array to establish a limit     
            $limit = count($_POST);

            //arranges the data into "key = value" format
            for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
                $prepFieldset[$i]  = "$groupKeys[$i] = $groupVal[$i]";
            }

            //prepares the fieldset to be used in SQL query
            $fieldset = implode(",",$prepFieldset);

             //process them in the model
             $status = $model->create($fieldset);

             //show response
             if($status == true){


                     $response = 'Data saved';

             }


             else{
                      $response = 'Error when saving data';
             }
            }
```